# Calendar Event via Intent does not set Start and End time

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I'm failing at setting the time for my event. It just does not get preset. This is my code:

```
private void makeCalendarEvent() {
    int year, month, month1, month2, day;

    day = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(date.charAt(4)) + Character.toString(date.charAt(5)));
    month1 = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(date.charAt(7)));
    month2 = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(date.charAt(8)));
    year = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(date.charAt(10)) + Character.toString(date.charAt(11)));

    Log.e("month", String.valueOf(month1 + month2));
    Log.e("year", String.valueOf(year));
    Log.e("day", String.valueOf(day));

    switch (month2) {
        case 1:
            if (month1 == 1) {
                month = Calendar.NOVEMBER;
            } else {
                month = Calendar.JANUARY;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (month1 == 1) {
                month = Calendar.DECEMBER;
            } else {
                month = Calendar.FEBRUARY;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            month = Calendar.MARCH;
            break;
        case 4:
            month = Calendar.APRIL;
            break;
        case 5:
            month = Calendar.MAY;
            break;
        case 6:
            month = Calendar.JUNE;
            break;
        case 7:
            month = Calendar.JULY;
            break;
        case 8:
            month = Calendar.AUGUST;
            break;
        case 9:
            month = Calendar.SEPTEMBER;
            break;
        case 10:
            month = Calendar.OCTOBER;
            break;
        default:
            month = Calendar.JANUARY;
    }


    Log.e("calendar", String.valueOf(month));

    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.clear();
    beginTime.set(20 + year, month, day, 23, 0);

    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.clear();
    endTime.set(20 + year, month, day + 1, 5, 0);


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, head)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, body)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Club Douala Ravensburg");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Output from my Logs:

```
03-13 22:34:28.787    6919-6919/? E/month﹕ 3
03-13 22:34:28.787    6919-6919/? E/year﹕ 14
03-13 22:34:28.787    6919-6919/? E/day﹕ 13
03-13 22:34:28.787    6919-6919/? E/calendar﹕ 2
```

So `Month`, `Day`, `Hour` and `Minute` do not get set. Don't know about `Year` but I guess thats ignored too

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you've messed up with year. Eg. for year 2014 you're setting 20+14 = 34. I think if your year is beyond 1970 year it can't be set.

Comment: DAAAAMN now that you've said it... Man that's stupid... haha.
Changing it to `2000+year` is what I should have done... THANK YOU